# Savinging numpy zip file via tensorflow GFile fails

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I've encountered a problem using `tf.io.gfile.GFile` with numpy. The example below demonstrates what I would expect to produce identical results. This works when I open the file with `open(...)`, but fails when I try the same with `GFile`. Is this to be expected for a reason that's unclear to me?

```
f = open('test.npz', 'wb+')
np.savez(file=f, x=np.array([1,2]))
f.close()
np.load('test.npz').files
['x']                                    # this is expected

f = tf.io.gfile.GFile('test.npz', 'wb+')
np.savez(file=f, x=np.array([1,2]))
f.close()
np.load('test.npz').files
[]                                       # this is wrong
```

Comment: Any particular reason not to use `read` / `write` operations of `GFile`? Personally feels like using read write functionality across libraries sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: You're suggesting writing numpy to a local file or to a byte array and then calling f.write() directly? I can load files using numpy from gfile without an issue. As is I re-wrote my code to write to a local temp file and then used `tf.io.gfile.copy` to move it to its destination (be that local or a remote filesystem supported by gfile). Since gfile provides a file-like object, it seemed hacky to apply any of these workarounds, at least not without understanding why I'm avoiding using gfile as normal file-like object.